# Laravel/Livewire: proxy for "system" routes

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laravel-livewire

I have **2 different Docker containers** with the *main website* and *Laravel forum*. Using `proxy_pass` in **nginx**, I'm routing `/forum` request to another Docker container. Everything works besides system **POST request inside Livewire** component.

For example, Livewire uses Notifications Provider and tries to reach it every 5 seconds using **POST**. This particular route always ends up with **404**, so it reaches my Laravel-Container, but Laravel doesn't know how to proceed with it, BUT! If I try this request with Postman, it works just fine!!

Error itself (browser console): `POST http://example.com/forum/livewire/message/layout.notifications 404 (Not Found)`

Nginx on the main (website) Docker:

```
    location /forum/ {
        proxy_pass http://MY_IP:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }

    location ~ ^/livewire/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://MY_IP:8081/livewire/$1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }

    location ~ ^/build/assets/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://MY_IP:8081/build/assets/$1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Log from main site:

```
site_beta | IP - - [19/Aug/2023:13:48:37 +0000] "POST /forum/livewire/message/layout.notifications HTTP/1.1" 404 6622 "http://example.com/forum/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "
```

Log from forum:

```
forum_beta    | LOCAL_IP - - [19/Aug/2023:13:48:37 +0000] "POST /livewire/message/layout.notifications HTTP/1.0" 404 6603 "http://example.com/forum/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "IP"
forum_beta    | - -  19/Aug/2023:13:48:37 +0000 "POST /index.php" 404
```

So Laravel becomes this POST-request, passes by proxy, it reaches Laravel's `index.php`, but it cannot be found by Livewire, but only in browser! I can even open this route (http://example.com/forum/livewire/message/layout.notifications) in browser and I see error 419 (method not allowed), but not 404!

I tried:

1. Rebuilding all containers with different rewrite rules;
2. Different browsers;
3. Different **app_url**, **asset_url** etc in Livewire.php (config)

I suppose, the problem is not with Docker/nginx/Laravel, it's something wrong with browser JS/script execution, because this request is made from JavaScript file with `fetch()`... But I have no idea already.

Comment: > ` I see error 419 (method not allowed)`. <<<=== 419 is not `method not allowed`. It indicates that you didn't send the csrf token with the post. Look into that first